# Could Not Find module "lightning/ariaObserver" LWC OSS

Tags: node.js, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss, node-salesforce

I am trying to implement a project with LWC OSS, when trying to import lightning-input I am facing the following error.

[image: Lightning/ariaObserver @somyatiwari59]

I tried to import the lightning-button and I was able to import the same successfully.
Only issue is with the input which has an import as lightning/ariaObserver
[image: Lightning-button working fine @somyatiwari59]

Here is the GitHub Code Link: """Removing Link due to some Reason."""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @sfdcfox it was the version issue with lightning-base components. I installed the version 1.13.9-alpha, and it started working. Although the changes are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@lwc/synthetic-shadow": "^2.6.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1043.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "lightning-base-components": "^1.13.9-alpha",
    "node": "^16.13.1",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
},
```

in the **package.json** file. the lwc.config.json remains the same as follows:

```
{
    "modules": [
        {
            "dir": "src/client/modules"
        },
        {
            "npm": "lightning-base-components"
        },
        {
            "npm": "aws-sdk"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was making a [mockup](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/6ZARev3QoGYxMhkoRfAB/src/app.html?p=stories) over the weekend for another answer, and I ran in to this exact same bug. To work around it, I downgraded to `lightning-base-components@1.13.9-alpha`. Fow now, try changing your `lwc.config.json` file to:

```
{
    "modules": [
        {
            "dir": "src/client/modules"
        },
        {
            "npm": "lightning-base-components@1.13.9-alpha"
        },
        {
            "npm": "aws-sdk"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm going to try and get a bug report filed for this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but it was a bit different from what you suggested. Posting the correct answer :)